# Не отображается "balloon" у иконки в системном трее. (WinAPI)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

Пытаюсь нарисовать иконку в трее и вывести сообщение, код следующий:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

int main(int _nArgCount, char * _pArgValues[]) {
    NOTIFYICONDATA nid = {};
    memset(&nid, 0, sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA));
    nid.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
    nid.hWnd = NULL;
    nid.uID = 1;
    nid.uFlags = NIF_ICON | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_TIP;
    nid.uCallbackMessage = WM_USER + 200;
    nid.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_INFORMATION);
    lstrcpy(nid.szTip, "Test Tip");

    Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &nid);

    lstrcpy(nid.szInfoTitle, "Text");
    lstrcpy(nid.szInfo, "Text");
    nid.szInfo;
    nid.dwInfoFlags = NIIF_INFO;

    Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, &nid);

    MSG msg = { 0 };
    int iGetOk = 0;
    while ((iGetOk = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0) {
            if (iGetOk == -1) return 3;
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Собственно `Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, &nid);` возвращает `true`, но ничего не всплывает. У меня win10. 
Может кто то знает, как это починить?

Comment: А почему `nid.hWnd = NULL` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский потому что окна не должно быть по идее программы. Но уже выяснили что без него (пусть скрытого) никак

Comment: ну да.. я на то и намекал немного, что дескриптор всегда должен быть) это как идентификатор приложения, какое оно бы не было

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ошибка №1.** Не указан дескриптор окна, которое будет обрабатывать сообщения от иконки. Без него иконка работать не может. На моей системе иконка всё же появляется, но при наведении на неё курсора мыши пропадает. Можно немного схитрить и сделать так:

```
nid.hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
```

Иконка теперь будет "привязана" к окну консоли, в котором запущена программа. Обратите внимание, что именно ***к окну консоли***, а не к запущенной программе - если программа завершится, но окно консоли останется, останется и иконка.

**Ошибка №2.** Неверные параметры при показе всплывающего сообщения. Во второй вызов `Shell_NotifyIcon` передаются те же параметры, что и в первый, следовательно, поля `szInfo` и `szInfoTitle` будут проигнорированы. Нужно указать, что мы меняем именно их, добавив перед вызовом `Shell_NotifyIcon` следующую строку:

```
nid.uFlags = NIF_INFO;
```

Вот минимальный работающий код (компилятор - *MinGW*):

```
#define STRSAFE_NO_DEPRECATE

#include <windows.h> 
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    NOTIFYICONDATA nid;
    memset(&nid, 0, sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA));
    nid.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
    nid.hWnd   = GetConsoleWindow();
    nid.uFlags = NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP;
    nid.hIcon  = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_INFORMATION);
    lstrcpy(nid.szTip, "Icon Tip");

    if (!Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &nid)) {
        printf("Error creating icon!");
        return -1;
    }

    Sleep(1000);

    lstrcpy(nid.szInfoTitle, "Balloon title.");
    lstrcpy(nid.szInfo, "Balloon text");
    nid.uFlags      = NIF_INFO;
    nid.dwInfoFlags = NIIF_INFO;

    if (!Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, &nid)) {
        printf("Error creating balloon!");
        return -1;
    }

    Sleep(5000);

    if (!Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, &nid)) {
        printf("Error deleting icon!");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ! Окна в моем приложении предполагается что не будет, потому и не делала сразу. Теперь так понимаю делать его надо, но прятать )

Comment: Да. Лучше всего будет создать простенькое скрытое окно исключительно для получения оконных сообщений.

Comment: @Abyx Кхм... :-( Да, верно... Спасибо. Поменял на `GetConsoleWindow`.

Comment: @Abyx пасиб за уточнения, winapi только осваиваю, любая инфа на вес золота :)

Comment: Не подскажете, почему MinGW не понимает dwInfoFlags, NIF_INFO, szInfoTitle, szInfo? shellapi.h подключен